# xticks and labels stuck on one side of the subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting 3 maps on one figure. For some reason when I go to label the xaxis the numbers are all crammed on one side of the plot. Is there anyone to space the values out?

```
for j in xrange(0,3):
        data = mydatalist[j]
        a.append(fig.add_subplot(3,2,j+1))]
        m.append(Basemap(projection='mill', llcrnrlat=-90, urcrnrlat=90, \
            llcrnrlon=30,urcrnrlon=390, resolution='c', ax=a[j]))

        x=np.linspace(30,390,288)
        y = np.linspace(-90, 90, 234)                                                                                                                
        x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)                                                                                                                     
        x, y = m[j](x,y)                                                                                                                             
        cintervals = [-0.1,-0.09, -0.08, -0.07, -0.06,-0.05, -0.04, -0.03, -0.02,-0.01,\                                                             
                 0, 0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.1]                                                                                

        mesh = m[j].contourf(x,y,data,cintervals, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
        xlab=np.concatenate([np.arange(30,181,30),np.arange(-150,31,30)])
        plt.xticks(np.linspace(30, 390, 13),xlab)
        plt.tick_params(labelsize=8) 

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is a guess, but the length of `x` is 288, while the length of `xticks` is 13.

Comment: @Scott changing to `plt.xticks(np.linspace(30, 390, 288),xlab)` doesn't make a difference

Comment: Can you post a small sample of `mydatalist[j]` and are `a` and `m` empty before entering the loop?

Comment: @Scott mydatalist[j] is an array of shape 234*288. a and m are empty before entering the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with co-ordinate mismatch between map coordinates and lat / long

You assign your x ticks to be displayed along the x axis spaced according to

```
np.linspace(30, 390, 13)
```

However - if you look at your values in `x` (i.e. the actual x co-ordinates that you are plotting against in the `contourf` line), you see they run from `0` to `40030154.74248523`.

To avoid this - replace

```
plt.xticks(np.linspace(30, 390, 13),xlab)
```

with

```
plt.xticks(np.linspace(min(x[0]),max(x[0]), len(xlab)),xlab)
```

---

***Note*** - you can produce this effect with a lot smaller but complete example, which might have helped you to isolate the issue.  Take a look at how to produce a [Minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  As it stands, your code doesn't run as it is missing `a`, `m`, `mydatalist` and the required imports.

I've put in the code below that you might have provided - retaining the subplot loop - although in reality you will likely get the same effect even with just one plot, rather than subplots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np

x=np.linspace(30,390,288)
y = np.linspace(-90, 90, 234)                                                                                                                
xg, yg = np.meshgrid(x, y)                                                                                                                     

fig = plt.figure()

for j in xrange(0,3):
        a = fig.add_subplot(3,2,j+1)
        m = Basemap(projection='mill', llcrnrlat=-90, urcrnrlat=90, llcrnrlon=30,urcrnrlon=390, resolution='c', ax=a)
        m.drawcoastlines() # Just put something on the map - doesn't need to be your complex contour plot
        x, y = m(xg,yg)    

        #You can see the problem with using hard-coded 30,390 if you print this
        #x=30 and x=390 are both in the lowest 0.001% of the x axis
        #print x                                                                                                                            

        xlab=np.concatenate([np.arange(30,181,30),np.arange(-150,31,30)])
        plt.xticks(np.linspace(30,390,13),xlab)

        #Working version commented below
        #plt.xticks(np.linspace(min(x[0]),max(x[0]), len(xlab)),xlab)
        plt.tick_params(labelsize=8) 

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Switching to a Gall Stereographic projection solved the problem for me, although i'm not sure why it does not work on a Miller projection.